# Whats the difference between Mini-A USB and Mini-B USB connector to power up Arduino Nano?

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano

I want to connect my Arduino Nano to PC via USB cable. It is described that it needs USB Mini-B connector. But all Mini-B cables are out of stock and only USB Mini-A are available. Will it work with Mini-A. Because I did not find any differences between those two types in terms of connector shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Mini-A will not work.

Type-A connectors are for upstream connections (PC) and Type-B for downstream  peripherals (Arduino)

Mini-A was a thing in early 2000s for USB-OTG applications but dropped out of the standard in 2007.

Also they have a different shape. Otherwise a different name wouldn't make much sense.

[image]

I don't know where you live but unless it's the Mount Everest it is rather impossible that you cannot get a A-Mini-B cable. Just pick another vendor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in both the cable types i.e., shape, pins etc. You cannot use type-A cable for your Arduino Nano to connect with your computer. I have a solution I used for some modules to program those, you can use FTDI programmer or Arduino UNO as ISP programmer for other Arduino boards, just you need to make some connections between Arduino UNO and Arduino Nano 6-pin jumper according to the pin configurations, the select exact port No. and use Arduino as ISP programmer in programmer setting in Arduino IDE. Here I suggest you to get connected with the SSLA technical support team for getting better assistance from them.